# XSLT Assign Function Return Value to Variable

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I can generate an id with this way:

```
<td id= "{generate-id(@value)}">

</td>
```

However, I want to assign it to a variable and use that variable. So, tried that:

```
<xsl:variable name="value_holder" select="{generate-id(@value)}" />
<td id= "{$value_holder}">

</td>
```

However XSLT doesn't work due to this line:

```
<xsl:variable name="value_holder" select="{generate-id(@value)}" />
```

How can store that variable and use it inside html element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has solved it:

```
<xsl:variable name="value_holder" select="generate-id(@value)" />
<td id= "{$value_holder}">

</td>
```